# Button Action using Reactive Cocoa

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

can anyone say how do i observe for action in Reactive Cocoa for a UIButton or UIControl..

An alternative way is to bind the view to the view model.And observe changes on the Mutable Property.

I tried using below code but none is firing.

```
 self.rollBtn.reactive.trigger(for: .touchUpInside).observeValues {
            value in

            print(value)

        }
```

EDIT: Actually i am trying to get the sender on button Tap..how can i do that?

Comment: Which version of `ReactiveCocoa` do you use?

Answer (score 3):

You have done nothing wrong in this code snippet - `trigger(for:)` is one of the ways to get notified in RAC 5.0. It should print `()` for every press on the button.

Have you linked the button with the view, if you are using Storyboard or Interface Builder? Where did you place this piece of code? Make sure you place it in `viewDidLoad` or `awakeFromNib` so that it gets called before the view is presented.

-

> EDIT: Actually i am trying to get the sender on button Tap..how can i do that?

As mentioned in the comments, `trigger(for:)` returns a `Signal<(), NoError>`. It doesn't include the sender with the `value` event. You would need to reference the sender manually, e.g.:

```
button.reactive
    .trigger(for: .touchUpInside)
    .observeValues { [unowned button] in
        _ = button
    }
```

Comment: @but why is that printing () ..how can i get the properties of a button..Or how should i use that ?

Comment: `trigger(for:)` gives a trigger of `Signal<(), NoError>` type. If you need to access the button, you will have to make your own transformation. e.g. `trigger(for: .touchUpInside).map { [unowned button] in button }`.

Would you mind to update your question with more details? I have tried to reproduce your problem but the simple snippet does not seem to have issues at all.

Comment: thanks...what does it returns when we observe values? while print it shoes as ()